# Как прикрепить элемент к нижней границе приложения MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Не нашел в решений в интернете, вот что у меня есть:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <FlexLayout Direction="Row"
                        JustifyContent="SpaceAround">
                <Image Source="main.png" 
                       HeightRequest="40"/>
                <Image Source="account.png"
                       HeightRequest="40"/>
            </FlexLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Пытался через AlignContent, AlignItems и AlignSelf, ничего не вышло

Comment: Создайте сетку, в которой будет 2 `Row`, одна имеющая высоту `*` (звезда - все доступное), а другая `Auto` (под размер содержимого, ну и помещайте в первую свой основной контент, а во вторую то, что должно быть в самом низу. `Stack` - это расположение объектов друг за другом, так обычно игнорируется положение, лишь очередность.